# Directive scope not removed when it was closed in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive like below :

```
angular.module('autoKeywords', []).directive('autosuggest',function(keywordService, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: '/some.html',
    scope: {
        onItemClick: '&',
        showFavIcon: "@",
        sectionName: "@",
        favouriteSection: "@",
        saveFavouriteSection: "@",
        encDetail: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
 //Some content
});
```

And I am using that direct in bootstrap modal. So when i closed that modal the scope of that directive remain there. I can see that in batarang.

And if remove that directive and close the modal scope removed properly.

Thanks

Comment: it may be because the bootstrap modal is just hidden and not removed from DOM ?

Comment: IMHO this is common with directive as we dynamically add them, so destroy element in general does not work. But I think you can refer this and see it works for you: http://www.mattzeunert.com/2014/11/03/manually-removing-angular-directives.html

Comment: @gaurav5430 It is removed from DOM too